# Should I use a MarketPlace action instead of a plain bash `cp` command to copy files?

Tags: github-actions

I am noticing there are many actions in the GitHub marketplace that do the same. Here is an example:
https://github.com/marketplace/actions/copy-file

Is there any benefit of using the GitHub marketplace action instead of plain bash commands? Do we have recommended practices guideline that helps to decide whether I use MarketPlace actions versus plain  bash or command line

Comment: Note: `cp` is an operating system command, not a bash command. You use `cp` within/through bash.

Comment: @Rob, thanks for help. When should I use the actions? I assume peope spent time to create so many actions for a reason?

Comment: I'm not sure why these seemingly simple actions exist, I would be suspicious of them myself and just use `cp`

Comment: @AnthonySottile, The problem is not just with 'cp' and there are many examples like this. Is there any official recommandation suggests when not to use actions and use plain bash commands?

Comment: @AllanXu there's no real reason to use Marketplace actions except convenience. Some of the Marketplace actions may provide some more stability across different workflow runner OSes. For example, `cp` may not be available or behave the same way on every OS. I agree with @Anthony Sottile, though - if you're using these Marketplace actions in a private repo with sensitive contents, you're potentially exposing those contents inadvertently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These actions don't seem to have any real value in my eyes...

Other than that, these run in docker and don't need `cp`, `wget` or `curl` to be available on the host, and they ensure a consistent version of their tools is used. If you're lucky these actions also run consistently the same way on Windows, Linux and Mac, where as your bash scripts may not run on Windows. But the action author would have to ensure this, it's not something that comes by default.

One thing that could be a reason to use these actions from the marketplace is that they can run as a post-step, which the `run: script/bash/pwsh` steps can't.

They aren't more stable or safer, unless you pin the actions on a commit-hash or fork it, the owner of the action can change the behavior of the action at any time. So, you are putting trust in the original author.

Many actions provide convenience functions, like better logging or output variables or the ability to safely pass in a credential, but these tasks seem to be more of an exercise in building an action by the author and they don't really serve a great purpose.

The documentation that comes with each of these actions, doesn't provide a clear reason to use these actions, the actions don't follow the preferred versioning scheme... I'd not use these.

---

So, when would you use an action from the marketplace...? In general actions, like certain cli's provide a specific purpose and an action should contain all the things it needs to run.

An action could contain a complex set of steps, ensure proper handling of arguments, [issue special logging commands to make the output more human-readable or update the environment for tasks running further down in the workflow](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions).

An action that adds this extra functionality on top of existing cli's makes it easier to pass data from one action to another or even from one job to another.

An action is also easier to re-use across repositories, so if you're using the same scripts in multiple repos, you could wrap them in an action and easily reference them from that one place instead of duplicating the script in each action workflow or adding the script to each repository.

GitHub provides little guidance on when to use an action or when an author should publish an action to the marketplace or not. Basically, anyone can [publish anything to the marketplace that fulfills the minimum metadata requirements for the marketplace](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/publishing-actions-in-github-marketplace).

[GitHub does provide guidance on versioning for authors, good actions should create tags that a user can pin to](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/creating-actions/about-custom-actions#using-tags-for-release-management). Authors should practice semantic versioning to prevent accidentally breaking their users. Actions that specify a branch like `main` or `master` in their docs are suspect in my eyes and I wouldn't us them, their implementation could change from under you at any time.

As a consumer of any action, you should be aware of the security implications of using any actions. Other than that, the author has 2FA enabled on their account, GitHub does little to no verification on any actions they don't own themselves. Any author could in theory replace their implementation with ransomware or a bitcoin miner. So, for actions you haven't built a trust relation with its author, it's recommended to fork the action to your own account or organization and that you inspect the contents prior to running them on your runner, especially if that's a private runner with access to protected environments. [My colleague Rob Bos has researched this topic deeply and has spoken about this topic frequently on conferences, podcasts and live streams](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDG40Y1nPEk).

Comment: Thanks, I'll delete my question as it is a duplicate. Could you give an example of a case where you would use a market place action and why these actions are different compared to the ones that you would use? Moreover, would it be possible to find some authoritative source describing what is best practice in this case?